# How to get the data instead of <azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_09_01.models.resource_sku_restrictions_py3.ResourceSkuRestrictions object at 0x071D8A10>?

Tags: python, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to fetch all the virtual machines details using from azure.mgmt.compute module ComputeManagementClient. As such I'm getting a json result of the data but at some places I'm getting this value . How do I get data from this object? Or please could you please explain what this means?

I haven't tried much because I'm not sure how to proceed forward with this kind of data

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

def trial(cred, subscription_id):
    GROUP_NAME = 'please provide the resource group name of your subscription'
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(cred, subscription_id)
    temp = {}
    for rsku in compute_client.resource_skus.list():
        temp[rsku.name] = {
            "tier": rsku.tier,
            "size": rsku.size,
            "family": rsku.family,
            "kind": rsku.kind,
            "capacity": rsku.capacity,
            "locations": rsku.locations[0],
            "costs": rsku.costs,
            "restrictions": rsku.restrictions
        }
    print(temp, "\n")


def authenticate():
    subscription_id = '0000000000000000000000000'
    try:
        credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
            client_id =  '00000000000000000000',
            secret = '0000000000000000000000',
            tenant = '00000000000000000000000'
        )
        return credentials, subscription_id
    except :
        return ("We are stuck")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cred, subscription_id = authenticate()    
    trial(cred, subscription_id)
```

```
'restrictions': [<azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_09_01.models.resource_sku_restrictions_py3.ResourceSkuRestrictions object at 0x071D8A10>]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there so figured out where I went wrong.

As such the output that was coming was a location of object.

So, I user

`print(dir(rsku))`

which gave out all the functions available for the object. The most relevant was value.

so I used
`print(rsku.restriction.value)`

Hope this helps